# What happens to the top and bottom part of a Portrait app designed for iPhone on iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

I am creating my portrait game for iPhone using @2x and @3x images for asset catalogs. I am yet to adjust assets for the iPad dimensions. The farthest sprites are 80px from the top and 60px from the bottom of an iPhone 6S+. How will this turn out on an iPad? Will more space be shown at the top and bottom or will my end sprites get truncated? If the end sprites will be truncated, how can I tell the region or maximum area that'll will be affected?

Comment: What happens when you test your app on an iPad simulator? What will happen depends entirely on how you've coded your game which no one here can tell from your description.

Comment: @RoboticCat As I stated, I am yet to adjust my assets for iPad dimensions, which will take quite a while before I can get them tested on the iPad simulator. I believe given the position of the farthest sprites at both ends on an iPhone 6S+ and additionally, that I am using the `aspectFill`  scale mode should be sufficient to know what could happen on an iPad.

Comment: You shouldn't have to adjust your assets for the iPad, if you are planning to use aspectFill, then you need to account for the top and the bottom getting chopped off (about 25% of your scene)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Should I be using the same 3x iPhone assets for iPad? I'm not using the universal asset catalog. What scale mode should I be using to prevent my assets from getting truncated? I would really appreciate if you could explain your previous comment further.

Comment: No, before we can figure out what you need, we need to figure out how you plan on envisioning your app across the multiple devices, because it sounds to me like you may want to be using resize fill

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I want my app to be available for iPhone 5 going up to iPad Pro. Everything seems okay with the iPhone asset category. Generally the bottom line is I need all sprites to appear on all devices. I really don't mind more space appearing at the bottom and top for some devices.

Comment: But you need to decide how you want it to look on all devices, do you want the ipad to show more content due to more screen space, or do you want it to show almost the same amount as the iphone

Comment: I would recommend making yourself a PNG of your scene across all iOS screens so you can determine how you want it to look

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The reason why this hasn't been too much of an issue for me is because I am using a plane/one color background,  but for aesthetics, I would like it to show almost the same amount.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I took your advice and made a .png. I realized what you said earlier about the top and bottom being cutoff on the iPad. How can I get the iPad to look similar to the iPhone 6? I really don't mind having extra space on the sides, but to get all the stuff on the top and bottom is the mot important thing.

Comment: I would design your app to be 4:3 then, but use the iphone 6+ size (so your scene would be 1920x1440,  this way your ipad would show more on the sides, and get cropped on iphone

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Does that mean I'll be having  `let gameScene = GameScene(size:  CGSize(width:480, height:640) , levelName:.level1)`?

Comment: you would take my number and divide by 3, so I think it would be 480

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so I have to redesign my iPhone6+ (3x) assets to 1920x1440. What about my iPhone6 (2x) assets what do they become?

Comment: 2x and 3x have to be the same multples of each other, so 2x is 1280x960

Comment: @Knight0fDragon okay, so iPhone6 assets become (1920/2, 1440/2). I think I now understand this

Comment: @Knight0fDragon but  (1920/2, 1440/2) gives 960x720. I am not sure how you arrives at 1280x960 for 2x. could you please explain this for me

Comment: That is 1.5x LOL,  You need to work up.  640 x 1. 640 x 2 640 x 3

Comment: @Knight0fDragon okay, and the iPad dimensions should be as usual, 768x1024 and 1024x1366 (since my game is portrait)? I just want to make sure I am on the right track

Comment: no, do not worry about ipad, the system will take care of it for you.  You only need to design in 1 size

Comment: @Knight0fDragon so I should only create assets for 2x and 3x using the universal asset categories instead of using the iPad and iPhone asset categories

Comment: Yes, unless you plan on making a completely different experience on iPad

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I guess this should work for me. It will take me quite a while to redesign my assets, but I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've spent quite a while adjusting my assets to look good with the 3:4 1440x1920 you recommended, but it isn't turning out well (it doesn't look right on the iPhone). What would you recommend I do, to work with different sizes for iPhone and iPad other than using the 3:4 ratio on iPhone?

Comment: I dont know what you are doing, you are clearly doing something wrong,  The iphones should be cropping the left and right sides

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I believe I’ve done the right thing per your instructions. The iPhones are cutting off the sides, but by my design I am not getting the experience I want after readjusting the sizes. That’s why i was thinking of an alternative, since the iPhone is the main device, I wouldn’t want to compromise too much on it’s experience. I would be willing to make more adjustment on the iPad than the iPhone

Comment: You should not be readjusting sizes, everything should be 1440x1920

Comment: The experience will always be different on iphone and ipad because the screens are different.  Your Ipad is suppose to have border fluff like we talked about.  You show more on the sides, but you do not have to actually use the sides, it is a fancy border

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I was referring to readjusting sizes from 1242x2208 to 1440x1920. But let's say I want to keep my dimensions for iPhone as they originally were. What other way can I adjust the dimensions for iPad?

Comment: Why is your size 1242x2208, you do not want to make it this size because you lose quality in your image.  You make it at the 1440x1920 size because that is the amount of pixels on your screen.  The iphone will scale it up, then scale it back down giving you perfect pixel images.The only reason that 2208x1242 exists is to keep PPI relatively close to the other devices, but I always felt the way it was executed is silly because your image does not retain the "inch" aspect of PPI, so it requires more work to be done if you want to handle this on screen

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I changed my size to 1440x1920 since you recommended it.  I am also initialing my gameScene in the following way `let gameScene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width:480, height:640) , levelName:.level1)` and using the `.aspectFill` scaleMode.  Not sure if I’m doing anything wrong but even when I test on the iPhone 6S+ the background has got black space at the top and bottom. I’ll appreciate if you could direct me to any simple samples projects, maybe from Github using your screen recommendation, that is if you know any.

Comment: is this landscape?  It is impossible to have black on top and bottom using aspect fill in portrait mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143300/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-itsmeagain).

Comment: @Knight0fDragon could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817782/leaving-equal-width-gap-spacing-before-and-between-menu-buttons for me

Comment: Just tag me on the questions you actually have problems with

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Would really appreciate it if you could assist me in anyway. There are some similarities with my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396983/how-to-add-the-iphone-x-screen-dimensions-to-the-mix-of-different-iphone-dimensi

Comment: @Containment, I do not do unity

Comment: @Knight0fDragon okay. But generally how would you take care the iPhone X dimensions using SpriteKit?

Comment: @Containment, no idea, I have been working in ARKit.  I would think it is the same as anything else, if you use aspectFill, just design around it and the hardware will take care of it.