# Leaving equal width gap spacing before and between menu buttons

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have created a scrolling menu using the code below. I am trying to create equal row gaps (width spacing) between each of the menu sprite buttons. Currently, I've been able to leave equal width spacing at the left and right ends but not in between sprite buttons. Please see the relevant code below:

```
class LevelScene: SKScene {

let levelButtonSize = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1").size
let levelButton1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b1")

let levelButton2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b2")
let levelButton3: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b3")
let levelButton4: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b4")
let levelButton5: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b5")
let levelButton6: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b6")
let levelButton7: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b7")
let levelButton8: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b8")

let levelButton9: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b9")
let levelButton10: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b10")
let levelButton11: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b11")
let levelButton12: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b12")

let levelButton13: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b13")
let levelButton14: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b14")
let levelButton15: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b15")
let levelButton16: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b16")
let levelButton17: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b17")
let levelButton18: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "b18")


private var scrollCell = SKSpriteNode()

private var moveAmtX: CGFloat = 0
private var moveAmtY: CGFloat = 0
private let minimum_detect_distance: CGFloat = 30
private var initialPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
private var initialTouch: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
private var resettingSlider = false

override init(size: CGSize){
  super.init(size: size)

     createMenu()
}

func createMenu() {

    let buttons = [levelButton1, levelButton2, levelButton3, levelButton4, levelButton5, levelButton6, levelButton7, levelButton8, levelButton9, levelButton10, levelButton11, levelButton12, levelButton13, levelButton14, levelButton15, levelButton16, levelButton17, levelButton18]

    for i in 1..<buttons.count  {
        buttons[i-1].name = "level\(i)"
    }

    let padding: CGFloat = 50
    let numberOfRows = CGFloat(buttons.count / 3)

    scrollCell = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: levelButtonSize.height * numberOfRows + padding * numberOfRows))
    scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.size.width / 2, y: 0 - (scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height / 2))
    scrollCell.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    scrollCell.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(scrollCell)

    //        let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bg")
    //        backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    //        self.addChild(backgroundImage)

    let totalMarginX = self.frame.width - 3*levelButtonSize.width
    let marginX = totalMarginX/4

    let column1PosX = marginX + levelButtonSize.width/2
    let column2PosX = 2*marginX + 3*levelButtonSize.width/2
    let column3PosX = 3*marginX + 5*levelButtonSize.width/2

    print("levelButtonSize.width is \(levelButtonSize.width)")
    print("self.frame.width is \(self.frame.width)")
    print("marginX is \(marginX)")
    print("column1PosX is \(column1PosX)")
    print("column2PosX is \(column2PosX)")
    print("column3PosX is \(column3PosX)")

    var colCount = 0
    var rowCount = 0

    for button in buttons {

        var posX: CGFloat = column2PosX
        if colCount == 0 {
            posX =  column1PosX
        }
        if colCount == 1 {
            posX =  column2PosX
        }

        else if colCount == 2 {
            posX =  column3PosX
            colCount = -1
        }


        let indexOffset = CGFloat(rowCount) * (levelButtonSize.height + padding)
        let posY = scrollCell.size.height - levelButtonSize.height / 2 - (indexOffset + padding / 2)
        button.position = CGPoint(x: posX, y: posY)
        //button.setScale(0.5)
        button.zPosition = 10
        scrollCell.addChild(button)

        if colCount == -1 {
            rowCount += 1
        }
        colCount += 1
    }
}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        self.scrollCell.removeAllActions()
        initialTouch = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)
        moveAmtY = 0
        initialPosition = self.scrollCell.position
    }
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.scene!.view)

        moveAmtX = movingPoint.x - initialTouch.x

        let topPos: CGFloat = scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height / 2
        let bottomPos = 0 - (self.size.height / 2)

        if (initialPosition.y - (movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y)) < -topPos {
            print("stop on top")
            moveAmtY = 0
            scrollCell.position.y = -topPos
        }
        else if (initialPosition.y - (movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y)) > bottomPos {
            print("stop on bottom")
            moveAmtY = 0
            scrollCell.position.y = bottomPos

        }
        else {
            moveAmtY = movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y
            scrollCell.position = CGPoint(x: initialPosition.x, y: initialPosition.y - moveAmtY)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}

func checkForResettingSlider() {

    let topPos: CGFloat = scrollCell.size.height - self.size.height / 2
    let bottomPos = 0 - (self.size.height / 2)

    if scrollCell.position.y > bottomPos {

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: bottomPos, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move)
    }

    if scrollCell.position.y < -topPos {

        let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -topPos, duration: 0.3)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut
        scrollCell.run(move)
    }
}

func yMoveActions(moveTo: CGFloat) {

    let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: (moveTo * 1.5), duration: 0.3)
    move.timingMode = .easeOut

    self.scrollCell.run(move, completion: { self.checkForResettingSlider() })
}
```

Please note that I set the scene in the following way:

```
 let levelScene = LevelScene(size: CGSize(width:480, height:640))
 levelScene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
 levelScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
 skView?.presentScene(levelScene)
```

**EDIT**

The image below shows a portion of my level menu which has more space between the level buttons as compared to the sides. I want to get the same width gaps between buttons and also at the sides.

[image]

Comment: can you put your image of the what you face as i see your code its seems to be correct calculation of x position

Comment: Can you output the values of `levelButtonSize.width`, `self.frame.width`, `marginX` and your `column1PosX`,`column2PosX`, `column3PosX` values and let us know what they are please?

Comment: can you check self.frame.width its value because i mad one small demo to see how your code work and its work like you want.so may be some other issue

Comment: @PaulBentley the values `levelButtonSize.width is 56.3333320617676,
 self.frame.width is 480.0,
 marginX is 98.8750004768372,
 column1PosX is 112.958333492279,
 column2PosX is 240.0,
 column3PosX is 367.041666507721`

Comment: `totalWidth=(480 - 3*56.3)=311.1`   : `marginX=totalWidth/4 = 311.1/4=77.75` : but you are stating that `marginX = 98.9` ?

Comment: @PaulBentley please pardon me, I just updated the code. What I posted at first was scaled and had with a few other changes.

Comment: Ok, so is the code now accurate, and is the value of 56.3 accurate?  Because still, (480- 3*56)/4=77.8, not 98.9 as your comment suggests.  Because, if you have a column1PosX of 112, then that looks correct.  The midpoint of the screen is 240, then halfway again to the left is 120.  112 approx 120 which would look a lot better.

Comment: @PaulBentley it seems as is we've not taken into consideration that `levelScene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`. That might be the issue.

Comment: If the anchor point was causing an issue, the whole scene would be around the origin.

Comment: Sounds to me like your images themselves are not centered.  If you attach the number to the button at anchor point (0.5,0.5) it will center

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Actually I have printed the numbers on the buttons. My main issue is getting equally width spacing before and between the buttons

Comment: oh then you want to 25% 50% and 75% of scene width

Comment: `let column1PosX =(scene.frame.width * 1) / 4`

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried `let column1PosX = self.frame.width/4,
        let column2PosX = 2*self.frame.width/4,
        let column3PosX = 3*self.frame.width/4`, but it leaves more spacing at the left and right ends as compared to between the buttons.

Comment: then your sprite anchor point is not 0.5 0.5

Comment: @Knight0fDragon my level scene has an anchor point of `CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` but I didn't set anchor points for the individual sprite buttons

Comment: well play around with all the anchor points

Comment: OH, if you are doing what I told you to do, then you need to test on an iPad,  iPhone would have cropping on sides

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you're right, iPad has equal width spacing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
let scaledWidth = levelButtonSize.width/2;
let totalMarginX = self.frame.width - 3*scaledWidth 
let marginX = totalMarginX/4 

let column1PosX = marginX + scaledWidth/2 
let column2PosX = 2*marginX + 3*scaledWidth/2 
let column3PosX = 3*marginX + 5*scaledWidth/2
```

Comment: This didn't work, it just made the margin widths slightly bigger

Comment: This thought was as a result of your call to `button.setScale(0.5)`